# how to move to previous step after form submission using wicked gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

In my multi-step form, if user move to previous step , the field data of current edited form  is lost as it is  not submitted. below is my view for form(move to previous or next) and controller respectively

```html
<%= f.submit "Previous",
  name: 'wizard_action',
  value: 'previous'
%>
<%= f.submit "Next",
  name: 'wizard_action',
  value: 'next'
%>
```

controller

```rb
def update
  @user.update(user_params)
  if params[:wizard_action] == 'next'
    render_wizard @user
  elsif params[:wizard_action] == 'previous'
    #need logic to move to previous step saving current step
  end
end
```

is there any way to move previous step directly from controller action? submitting current form.

Comment: https://github.com/zombocom/wicked#quick-reference